Open3d Point light in rendering scene not working
I want to display a STL-model using open3d. To highlight the edges better, I want to add additional lighting to the scene. However, I fail to get the renderer and the light functions to work.
My current code:
import open3d as o3d
import open3d.visualization.gui as gui
import open3d.visualization.rendering as rendering
import time
import numpy as np
count = 1

def capture_img(vis):
    global count
    time.sleep(3)
    #vis.capture_screen_image(f'test{count}.png', True)
    count += 1
    ctr.rotate(30.0, 0.0)
    return False


mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("cad/Plug01_simplified_detailed2.STL")
mesh = mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
mesh.paint_uniform_color([1, 0, 0])

vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
vis.create_window()
vis.add_geometry(mesh)


print(vis.get_window_name())

ctr = vis.get_view_control()
ctr.change_field_of_view(step=-90)  # drastically reduced perspective effect
vis.register_animation_callback(capture_img)

renderer = o3d.visualization.rendering.Renderer
scene = o3d.visualization.rendering.Scene
color = np.array([1., 1., 0.], dtype=np.float32)
position = np.array([3., 3., 0.], dtype=np.float32)
scene.add_point_light('light', color, position, 1e8, 1e2, True)


vis.run()
vis.destroy_window()

At the moment I receive the error message:
add_point_light(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: open3d.cpu.pybind.visualization.rendering.Scene, name: str, color: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float32[3, 1]], position: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float32[3, 1]], intensity: float, falloff: float, cast_shadows: bool) -> bool

Invoked with: 'light', array([1., 1., 0.], dtype=float32), array([3., 3., 0.], dtype=float32), 100000000.0, 100.0, True

I just do not see how my Input is wrong. Is the renderer and the scene object correctly defined? Am I missing some wrong data type in the function arguments?
Thanks and best regards.
I tried to use a gui object instead of the visualizer but did not get that to work either.

I believe you are mixing two different ways of rendering into one. The Visualizer class (legacy) and the Scene class (modern) do not mix.
What makes Open3D a bit complicated especially when it comes to Visualization is availability of multiple modules.
There are currently (as of version 0.18.0) tutorials available on following classes:-

open3d.visualization.draw_geometries which is a simple wrapper over open3d.visualization.Visualizer.
open3d.visualization.Visualizer which allows for dynamic and interactive visualization of 3D data.
open3d.visualization.draw_geometries_with_editing which is again a simpler wrapper over VisualizerWithEditing. There are a few more customized samples available here https://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.visualization.html.
o3d.web_visualizer.draw for drawing in Jupyter using webrtc protocol..

However, the modern Visualization tools built over Filament  are missing proper tutorials. Some of these are:

open3d.visualization.draw which uses open3d.visualization.O3DVisualizer and provides access to Scene, however this is read-only.
open3d.visualization.rendering.OffscreenRenderer that can be used to render to image.
open3d.visualization.gui.* which provides ways to design gui and uses open3d.visualization.rendering.* for rendering.

The below code shows how to setup a point light in your scene using either O3DVisualizer or OffscreenRenderer.
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
import open3d.visualization.gui as gui
import open3d.visualization.rendering as rendering

mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(o3d.data.BunnyMesh().path)
mesh = mesh.compute_vertex_normals()

color = np.array([0., 0., 1.], dtype=np.float32)
position = np.array([1., 1., 0.], dtype=np.float32)

use_o3dvisualizer = False
if use_o3dvisualizer:
    gui.Application.instance.initialize()
    window = o3d.visualization.O3DVisualizer("ModernUI")
    window.add_geometry("mesh", mesh)
    window.reset_camera_to_default()  # Set camera nicely.
    window.scene.scene.add_point_light('light', color, position, 1e8, 1e2, True)

    gui.Application.instance.add_window(window)
    gui.Application.instance.run()
    gui.Application.instance.quit()
else:
    render = rendering.OffscreenRenderer(640, 480)

    yellow = rendering.MaterialRecord()
    yellow.base_color = [1.0, 0.75, 0.0, 1.0]
    yellow.shader = "defaultLit"

    box = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_box(2, 2, 1)
    box.compute_vertex_normals()
    render.scene.add_geometry("bunny", mesh, yellow)

    render.scene.scene.add_point_light('light', color, position, 1e8, 1e2, True)
    render.scene.scene.enable_sun_light(False)
    render.scene.show_axes(True)

    render.setup_camera(60.0, [0, 0, 0], [-0.25, 0.25, 0], [0, 1, 0])
    img = render.render_to_image()
    print("Saving image at test.png")
    o3d.io.write_image("test.png", img, 9)


BTW, not all information in the above answer is 100% correct as there is no tutorials on these. I have been mostly using them as needed and learning directly from code.
